# How to make only one filed true in a MySql table at one time?

Tags: mysql

[image]

I have a table tblsessions. At one time, only one session could be current as is session 2014-2015.

However, if i make 2015-2016 current, 2014-2015 should not be current anymore.

**How could I implement this logic in table at design time?**

Here is the table creation code waiting for your modification:

```
create table tblsessions(
    sessionid int not null auto_increment,
    sessionname varchar(9) not null,
    current ????
    primary key (sessionid)
);
```

Comment: Another option was to create a STORED PROCEDURE and call it through TRIGGER, but issue remains the same. So far, I find that there is no solution to this problem at MySql level. What a pity!

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use a trigger (depending on the version of MySQL you're running). I've assumed that `current` is a tinyint but you can adjust to whatever type you use:

```
CREATE TRIGGER curr_check BEFORE UPDATE ON tblsessions
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.current = 1 THEN
            UPDATE tblsessions SET current = 0; 
        END IF;
    END;
```

EDIT:
A.5.3: Does MySQL 5.6 have statement-level or row-level triggers?

In MySQL 5.6, all triggers are FOR EACH ROW—that is, the trigger is activated for each row that is inserted, updated, or deleted. **MySQL 5.6 does not support triggers using FOR EACH STATEMENT.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Currently, I am using mysql 5.6.17, however what if I upgrade mysql. Would I have to revisit trigger?

Comment: That version should be fine I think. Worth a try anyway! I'd test on a test table

Comment: The current value could be updated at insertion of new session as well, would this trigger work for insertion? I never used triggers before

Comment: You could also create in `INSERT` version. Same syntax, but use `BEFORE INSERT`

Comment: This is the error: #1442 - Can't update table 'tblsessions' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Answer (score 0):

**ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION:**

I have come up with another solution however I wonder if it really is a good solution.

I have created two tables:

```
TBLSESSIONS (session) 
// session is primary key and stops duplicates

TBLCURRENTSESSION (csessionid, csession) 
// csessionid is auto-int 
// csession is foreign key to TBLSESSIONS.session
```

Each time user presses a button [Make This Session Default], I can insert that session into csession.

In code I can search for largest csessionid and find csession against it as the CURRENT SESSION.

This also allows user to switch sessions at time.

**Being MySQL DBA, do you think it is a good approach to solving my basic problem?** Do you see any dark sides of this solution?